# how do i configure entity framework to handle a default date constraint

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6, and when I try to create a new record I get the following error.  However, I have a default value on the column, so that when the record is created, it gets a timestamp from the DB.

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

In my table, I have a [created] column with a default constraint:

```
[Created] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Notice_Created]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
```

In my Class, I have a Created Property:

```
public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

In my Mapping Class, I have:

```
this.Property(t => t.Created).HasColumnName("Created");
```

What configuration do I need to use, to have EF not try and create the column with a default value?

Answer (score 0):

Try using DateTime? as your type (it's called a nullable type)