# Guid into NewId column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm currently trying to add a unique Guid property on row insert in SQL Server. I am doing this via Entity Framework 6. To add the column to the table, I used the following query:

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.Reservation ADD ConfirmationID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  DEFAULT (NEWID()) WITH VALUES
```

Whenever I create a new row in this table, the `NEWID()` is always set to `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. I have tried to create a new Guid for the property in C# before my insert, however this returns the same result.

Here is the C# code I am calling as part of the insert function:

```
public ReservationClientModel Create(ReservationClientModel clientModel)
    {
        var reservation = new Reservation();
        reservation = Mapper.Map<ReservationClientModel, Reservation>(clientModel, reservation);
        reservation.ConfirmationID = new Guid();

        _repository.Add(reservation);

        _context.Commit();

        return Mapper.Map<ReservationClientModel>(reservation);
    }
```

Here is the code generated from EF as seen from EF Profiler:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Reservation]
   ([RoomID],
    .....
    .....
    [ConfirmationID])

VALUES (15 /* @0 - [ID] */,
    .... 
    ....
    '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' /* @13 - [ConfirmationID] */)
```

Is there any way I can set this property to add a `NEWID()` on insert, without setting the property in C# before hand?

Comment: isn't it Guid.NewGuid() ?

Comment: Are you using `DEFAULT` in the insert? `values(1, 2, DEFAULT)` ?

Comment: you are also calling default on the guid, get rid of default

Comment: @Brino: This question is about a SQL statement, not about C# code.

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642068/how-to-get-ef-6-to-handle-default-constraint-on-a-database-during-insert

Comment: @Brino This actually works, but ideally I'd like the value to be set in the SQL end, rather than in C#

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(id int, val uniqueidentifier DEFAULT (NEWID()) )

INSERT INTO #temp(id) values(1)
SELECT * FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

But beware if those confirmationId should be your primary key in your design. This would be very bad and will perform very bad.

Comment: The issue is when inserting using EF

Comment: yes but would should be different? If it's inside the dbms, it should work the same.

Comment: Your comment about performance is not true. A GUID as a primary key can perform just fine. It is when the GUID is the clustered index that the performance goes downhill.

Comment: Yes and if you poorly use the SSMS - which most beginners do - the system takes the primary as template for the clustered index indirectly. ;-) I just wanted to warn before the performance is decreased. ;-)

Comment: Nothing wrong with warning. I was clarifying because your statement was not true. Any table that has a primary key defined will by default also be the clustered index unless you explicitly state that it should be nonclustered or if a clustered index already exists.

Comment: @Ionic - if the application passes `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` your default constraint on the database side will be ignored. OP wants to exclude the column using EF

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry didn't get that. Well another idea is to set a after insert trigger which will react on this case and generate a new guid for this.

Comment: @Ionic, That is a good idea, but I will try and see if it is doable as part of the transaction first.

Comment: Reasonable yes. Because trigger could have side-effects. But if this fails, I would suggest the trigger. Do you get it by your self with the trigger or do you need a example?

Comment: @Ionic, Yeah I can implement a trigger if need be, thanks though!